# How can I use struct as key?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, key, stdmap

I have the following code, I've got some errors like:

```
struct duplicatedTurns
    {
        int nodeId;
        int min;
        int max;

        bool operator==(const duplicatedTurns& other) const
        {
            return nodeId == other.nodeId && min == other.min && max == other.max;
        }

I solved it here to following code:
bool operator<(const duplicatedTurns& other) const
{
if (nodeId != other.nodeId) return nodeId < other.nodeId;
if (min != other.min) return min < other.min;
if (max != other.max) return max < other.max;
return false;
}

    };
```

The container that I want to use:

```
std::map<duplicatedTurns, int> selected;
```

After i would like to insert elements there:

```
selected.insert(duplicatedturns{it->nodeId, std::min(it->toLinkId, it->fromLinkId), std::max(it->toLinkId, it->fromLinkId)}, "here: increment the number if the key are the same" );
```

Comment: "Some errors" is not very helpful. What errors are you getting?

Comment: To use a `struct` as a key, you need to have a comparison operator `<`.

Comment: There must be an overload of `operator<` for the key of `std::map` . Your key only overloads `operator==` (as far as we can see)

Comment: This is the first time I ever use struct as key. I saw that question and asnwares. I have multiple variables and I don't understand how implement that.

Comment: If you don't know how to compare your struct than how should anyone else? There is not much of differnce to `operator==`

Comment: I was about to write an answer. I got [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Mq1hG6) far. Perhaps  it's enough to get you going.

Comment: The error doesn't mention anything about `operator<`, the error is about invalid use of `insert`. Change it to `emplace`, or wrap your arguments in `{}` to construct an `std::pair` object.

Comment: @TedLyngmo. Thank you this is what i mean for. I figured it out by the way.

Comment: @MarcellJuhasz Great! Happy hacking! :-) You recommend using `std::tie` for the logic in `operator<` though. It makes it _a lot_ easier to read and maintain. It's also very easy to make errors when creating the operator to comply with the _strict weak ordering_  a map requires.

Comment: "You" should be "I" above :-)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use struct as key in a std::map?

Either by making the class less-than comparable using the default comparison function of `std::map` which is `std::less` (this can be achieved by defining overload for `operator<` which satisfies the specified requirements), or by providing a custom comparison function as a template argument for `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ Map is ordered by default. That's why operator< has to be defined, so it could sort elements.